# illogical Passport authenticate method arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

Trying to understand
https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/master/lib/middleware/authenticate.js , at line 57.

I dont understand why the passport authenticate method has 4 arguments :

```
module.exports = function authenticate(passport, name, options, callback){/*code*/}
```

In practice it's used like this:

```
passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/', failureRedirect: '/login' });
```

or

```
passport.authenticate('local', function(req, res));
```

So how come the first argument "passport" in the method définition is not interfering ? Since the strategy name is passed as first argument, it should be mapped to passport not to name.

Comment: If this were Python I would tell you that the first argument receives the object `passport` from the expression `passport.authenticate`.  Javascript normally doesn't work that way but I would not be surprised to learn that someone has found a way to *make* it work that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed an intermediate layer [here](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/e3e98788b1855823d81422d67d553901642cd945/lib/authenticator.js#L162-L164):

```
Authenticator.prototype.authenticate = function(strategy, options, callback) {
  return this._framework.authenticate(this, strategy, options, callback);
};
```

The `passport` variable is an instance of the `Authenticator` class, so the method above represents `passport.authenticate()`. As you can see, it passed a reference to itself as first argument to the function that you're referring to (which is referred to by `this._framework.authenticate`).